# Change the colour of the iphone active links

Tags: css, iphone

I want to change the colour of the black transparent effect thats applied to buttons when using the iphone.

I've noticed Fantasy Football have achieved this with a transparent pink effect when buttons are hit.
Please load on iphone - http://fantasy.premierleague.com/

I've tried using the a:active tag but it doesn't work with the iphone, any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I was searching for:

```
a:link {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #f7c923;
}
```